# How to create a simple client testimonial carousel using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to learn how to create a very simply client testimonial carousel using jQuery.

This is how my client testimonial section looks like:

[image: Custom Client Testimonials Block]

**Here is my HTML code for this section:**

```
  <!-- TESTIMONIALS SECTION -->

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="indent-top">
          <h2 class="space-after">Отзывы<br> от наших клиентов</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">

        <div id="client-1" class="sss">
          <img class="testimonial-photo" src="assets/img/testimonials/clients/client-1.jpg">
          <h3 class="client-name">Евгений Карев</h3>
          <p class="client-description space-after">Генеральный директор,<br><strong>SIA INTERGAZ</strong></p>
          <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2 space-after">
            <p>“Сотрудничеством доволен, нареканий нет. Ни разу не нарушили сроков. Очень рад, что сами занимаются оформлением документов, так что мне не приходится в это лезть.”</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="client-2" class="hide">
          <img class="testimonial-photo" src="assets/img/testimonials/clients/client-2.jpg">
          <h3 class="client-name">Александр Карев</h3>
          <p class="client-description space-after">Директор по Маркетингу,<br><strong>SIA INTERGAZ</strong></p>
          <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2 space-after">
            <p>“Сотрудничеством доволен, нареканий нет. Ни разу не нарушили сроков. Очень рад, что сами занимаются оформлением документов, так что мне не приходится в это лезть.”</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="client-3" class="hide">
          <img class="testimonial-photo" src="assets/img/testimonials/clients/client-3.jpg">
          <h3 class="client-name">Иварс Викелис</h3>
          <p class="client-description space-after">Финансовый директор,<br><strong>SIA INTERGAZ</strong></p>
          <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2 space-after">
            <p>“Сотрудничеством доволен, нареканий нет. Ни разу не нарушили сроков. Очень рад, что сами занимаются оформлением документов, так что мне не приходится в это лезть.”</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="client-4" class="hide">
          <img class="testimonial-photo" src="assets/img/testimonials/clients/client-1.jpg">
          <h3 class="client-name">Сергей Кривошеев</h3>
          <p class="client-description space-after">Директор по ИТ,<br><strong>SIA INTERGAZ</strong></p>
          <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2 space-after">
            <p>“Сотрудничеством доволен, нареканий нет. Ни разу не нарушили сроков. Очень рад, что сами занимаются оформлением документов, так что мне не приходится в это лезть.”</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 text-center indent-bottom">
         <ul>
           <li id="client-1-selector" class="client-selector active-client"></li>
           <li id="client-2-selector" class="client-selector"></li>
           <li id="client-3-selector" class="client-selector"></li>
           <li id="client-3-selector" class="client-selector"></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

So basically I have four different testimonials, where three of them are hidden using Bootstrap **.hide** class and the first testimonial is unhidden. Below these testimonials I have four client selectors (round dots), which when pressed should trigger a script with the following logic:

1. When **".client-2"** (round dot selector below testimonial) is pressed, the script should automatically remove **".hide"** class from the **#client-2** (second testimonial) and give all the other testimonials a class of **".hide"** to hide them from the user. Thus, as far as I understand the script should check whether a certain testimonial already has a ".hide" class and if it does not than add this class to the given testimonial.

One thing to mention here is that I am not a very experienced user in JavaScript and jQuery (just yet), but this is as far as I got with this script:

```
$("body").on("click", "#client-2-selector", function(){
    $("#client-1").addClass('hide');
    $("#client-2").removeClass('hide');
    $("#client-1-selector").removeClass("active-client");
    $("#client-2-selector").addClass("active-client");
});
```

This script sort of works: http://d.pr/i/1hXN (this is a .gif file showing how it works now).

I understand that there should be a much better way of achieving the same result for all four **client testimonial selectors** because if I will use my method than I will need to add a lot of identical code, which is not DRY... Therefore, I would be highly grateful if someone could help me out with this script or give me some sort of suggestion on how I could improve it.

*P.S I know that there are different plugins for achieving the desired effect, such as: http://flickity.metafizzy.co/ , but as a beginner I would like to practice my skills, thus I decided to do everything myself to get some deeper understanding of how things actually work.*

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".client-selector", function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    $("[id^='client-']:not(.client-selector)").addClass('hide');
    $("#client-"+(index+1)).removeClass('hide');
    $(".client-selector").removeClass("active-client");
    $(this).addClass("active-client");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nueL8utm/

Comment: Hi there, thank you very much for the help. I've inserted your script, and it seems to work for the last two parts i.e. 

`$(".client-selector").removeClass("active-client");
    $(this).addClass("active-client");`

Meaning that the colour for the selectors is changing accordingly, but the content i.e. photo, name and the quote does not change. Will do my best to workout the logic of your script to make it work, but if you could assist me with it, it would be really great ;) thanks.

Comment: Niiiice! It works as expected. Thank you very much for the help! Much appreciated.